# DownloadString works for HTTP but not for HTTPS

Tags: https, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, webclient, downloadstring

I have webclient call in my SSIS package which call an API to get JSON response.

```
            using (var mySSISWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                mySSISWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                var result = mySSISWebClient.DownloadString(jsonURLwithDate);
            }
```

When I change the URL to use HTTPS, the package is failing at downloadstring call with the following error.

**Download failed: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**

It is working fine when I have the URL with HTTP. I am working on it in SSDT 2010. Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the following code to implement TLS1.2:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

based on this article

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: Add it as the very first line. I had to do this for similar web services using VS2010.